# Is it possible to invert the mask for GPUImageMaskFilter?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, gpuimage

I am masking a photo with a frame mask image. The mask was created for Core Graphics which is inverted.

Black means "visible" and white means "fully transparent". The opposite of Photoshop masks.

Is it possible to invert the mask for the filter so the effect is reversed?

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to change rgb color to inverse.
In a Fragment shader, you can do this exprestion

```
uniform sampler2D tex0 ;
uniform sampler2D tex1; // mask
void main()
{
vec4 nowcolor = texture2D(texture1, uv);
vec4 newmask = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0) - nowcolor;

// and use the new mask here instead the old mask texture

}
```